# PICO ASM: Conversion between pioasm and adafruit_pioasm MOV command

Tags: pi-pico, circuitpython

I am running CircuitPython on a Raspberry Pi Pico and I am attempting to do some pioasm, which is different on CircuitPython than in MicroPython.

According to the [adafruit pioasm documentation](https://learn.adafruit.com/intro-to-rp2040-pio-with-circuitpython):

> #### Major differences between adafruit_pioasm and standard pioasm
>
> - .wrap and .wrap_target are not supported
> - mov operator restrictions
> - Expressions are not supported

I get the first point, but the other two require more detail, and I am not sure where to find that. However my question mainly revolves around converting the following "standard" PIOasm code to adafruit_pioasm code:

```
    // line 81 & 82
    set x, 0                ; load x register with 0 (we can't set more than 5 bits at a time)
    mov pins, !x            ; write inverted x (0xff) to row pins latching them all high
```

[original PIO code](https://discord.gg/adafruit)

As far as I can tell this should just equate to

```
    set x, 0                ; load x register with 0 (we can't set more than 5 bits at a time)
    set y, 1                ; !0 is 1, right???
    mov pins, y             ; write inverted x (0xff) to row pins latching them all high
```

I know I have other issues with the creation of the `rp2pio.StateMachine` object, which I am still working on, but I would like to know if I have corrected the assmebly language correctly.

I am aware that some of this might seem off-topic, however I would appreciate it if it can be acknowledged:

- This stackexchange network is for Raspberry Pi products, including the Pico
- It could be suggested where this SHOULD go if not here. I have checked https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and they have less tags than this one, I have also asked on the [Adafruit discord channel](https://discord.gg/adafruit) `help-with-rp2040-pio` with no success.

Comment: It seems like help is thin on the ground for the pico, especially for CircuitPython. I'm not even sure the first bullet point is true. Adafruit's own neopixel example in circuitpython clearly uses .wrap and .wrap_target !

Comment: Yeah I suspect that it's going to get closed... but I don't know where else to ask. I've actually given up on the Pico now anyway